# Odd CSS behavior in IE7 unordered list

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a drop down list that I'm trying to get working in IE7. Amongst other bugs, the one that has me beat is the anchors on hover not pushing the background to full padding height. It seems to stay within the dimensions of its li and ultimately the ul. I've tried expanding the height of both ul and li but this doesn't seem to work. Works correctly in all other browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/gzLVR/2/

What you should see: The anchor tag, on hover, should expand at the bottom by 50px (as per the css `#menu > ul > li:hover > a { padding-bottom:50px; }`. This expansion is performed, but the background-color doesn't seem to push to the anchor's margins.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Smamatti: It's tagged IE7, so I assume that's the one he's having issues with.

Comment: Yes, sorry. This error is exclusively in IE7, I just checked in IE8 and the specific background bug is not experienced in that version. I'll update the question.

Comment: Doh! I didn't look at the tags. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution myself. Each li's anchors are by default set to wrap around it's content (display:inline?), and setting the display to inline-block is somewhat dangerous as its behavior in IE7 is somewhat unpredictable.

By simply setting the anchor to display:block, you allow it to take on dimensions of itself in IE7, so you break it away from having it simply wrap around its content. Thus, it's possible for it to affect the needed padding when on hover.

This will now work in IE7:
http://jsfiddle.net/gzLVR/5/

Answer (score 0):

IE7 does not support `:hover` on items other than `<a>` tags. Since you have your `:hover` on an `<li>` it is not working in IE7.

You'll need to add some javascript to add a `.hover` class to the `<li>` when you mouseover, and then adjust your css to include it as well:

```
#menu > ul > li:hover > a,
#menu > ul > li.hover > a{ 
    padding-bottom:50px; 
}
```

[EDIT]
It appears this is only true when IE7 renders in quirksmode. If you are using a strict doctype, you should be able to use `:hover` on an `<li>`

Comment: I'll look into this, but I've checked if the anchor expands on hover by strictly using css, and the IE debugger (on IE9, in IE7 Browser and document mode) shows me that it does indeed expand as it should. It seems it's really the background that doesn't seem to want to push to its elements new dimensions.

Comment: I don't think this is true - I just tried `LI:hover` on IE7 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the anchor to

```
display:inline-block; 
zoom:1;
```

The `zoom` should only be required for IE7, it triggers '[hasLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'

Answer (score 0):

I think trigger [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) will fix it; you can do it with somthin like this:

```
#menu > ul > li > a { display: inline-block;}
```

Be aware of that IE don't supports `:last-child` [up to IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoclasses), but you can use `:first-child`.

I would also suggest to use a pseudo element for the part you used the `<i></i>`, so you don't have unneccessary markup in your HTML.